# on mouse up change button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a set of buttons. I want that when I do mouse up on one of the buttons, that particular button will change its back colour while all the other will remain the same.

Any help on how to do it without having any post back.?

Comment: Just use an onclick handler on the button. In an `asp:Button`, you write `OnClientClick` for an attribute (as opposed to `OnClick`, which does a postback).

Comment: use CSS pseudo selector `:hover`

Comment: On mouse _up_? You don't want to change it on mouse _down_ and then reset it on mouse _up_? If you only do it on mouse _up_ the colour change will be permanent... Please show the html for the buttons, and whatever object they're contained by (assuming they're in a form or div or something).

Comment: @ jibi not on mouse hover I want but on mouse click up.

Comment: @nnnn I have 5 buttons and what I want is that each time I click on one of the buttons, taht particular button will change the backcolour and than back to its original color when I click on another button.

Comment: So please edit your question to say so clearly, and also show your html.

Comment: ...after 50min... Is it so hard to show us a HTML or even a JS of your try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5: is there an "onrelease" like event for input type range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199098/html5-is-there-an-onrelease-like-event-for-input-type-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly clunky way to do it:

```
<style>
.selected { background-color : red; }
</style>
<script>
var theForm = document.getElementById("someForm");
theForm.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // allow for IE
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    var src = e.srcElement || e.target;

    if (src.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input"
        && src.type.toLowerCase() === "button"){
        src.className = "selected";
        for (var i = 0; i < theForm.children.length; i++)
            if (src != theForm.children[i])
                theForm.children[i].className = "";
    }             
};
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yn3pT/

This assumes the buttons are children of a form called "someForm" and that a class "selected" exists that has the appropriate colour - obviously you'll modify this as appropriate to suit your markup.

Note that the above should either be in an onload handler or the script block should be somewhere after the elements in the source.

Note also that `onclick` would be much more appropriate than `onmouseup` for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="mouseup"> Click me </button>
<button class="mouseup"> Click me </button>
<button class="mouseup"> Click me </button>
```

​

```
$buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('mouseup');

for(var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; i++ )
{
     $buttons[i].onmouseup= function(){
        this.style.background = 'blue';  
        for(var j = 0; j < $buttons.length; j++ )
            if( $buttons[j] != this ) 
                $buttons[j].style.background = '#F0F0F0'; 
     }
}
```

​

​

http://jsfiddle.net/nQHup/5/
​