# Is there an HTML attribute/event handler for 'on mouse release'?

Tags: html, attributes, event-handling

I need a function to be called when the slider knob has been released.
`onchange` changes the value while I'm changing it. Is there a solution for this like

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1000" onrelease="callfunction()">
```

Comment: The example is a bit odd, since such an element lets the user choose just between 0 and 1. It should have a suitable `step` attribute, e.g. `step="0.01"` (or a different `max` attribute).

Comment: I just changed the original code for simplicity, also the question has already been answered

Comment: Just because it has been answered does not mean it should not be corrected. If you want to simplify it and make the element meaningful, you can just default both `min` and `max`.

Comment: the thing is it wasn't wrong on the first place, I just simplified the code of the original project.
the values min and max are completely irrelevant, the only relevant attribute is "onrelease" which doesn't exist

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) event on desktop browsers and the [`touchend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/touchend_event) event on mobile phones for handling this user interaction.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" 
       onmouseup="callfunction()" 
       ontouchend="callfunction()">
```

I would recommend to check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=range%20input) for browser support.

**Known issues (as of 2019-03-25):**

- IE10 & 11 [fire the "change" event instead of "input"](https://hparra.github.io/html5-input-range/) on mousemove.
- IE10 & 11 have [some bugs related to the step value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241415/html5-number-input-field-step-attribute-broken-in-internet-explorer-10-and-inter).

Comment: This appears to be the practical solution. Event handling for `input type=range` is different in different browsers (and still really experimental). Just moving the slider causes `change` events in IE, `input` events in Firefox, and both of them in Chrome! But releasing it triggers `onmouseup` in all of them. This might not work in implementations that do not use a mouse in this context.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - You are absolutely right. This won't work e.g. for touch devices.

Comment: But does this also work on touch devices? What would be the equivalent event there?

Comment: This won't cover users who use the keyboard to modify the range (e.g. users who don't use a pointing device for accessibility reasons).

Answer (score 3):

[tomhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902408/tomhughes) makes a good point re: accessibility.

It's possibility to add [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) to the list:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" 
   onmouseup="callfunction()" 
   ontouchend="callfunction()"
   onkeyup="callfunction()"
>
```