# Getting last value of slider

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using HTML slider (`type="range"`). It updates relevant element for each intermediate value while going to target value. Because it is a big data rendering project, it causes the application to slow down. I want it to take only for its last value, not intermediate values.

I'm using this element in a React project. I have encountered that MaterialUI has `onChangeCommitted` event but I do not want to use an external library.

Is there any way to simulate this `onChangeCommitted`?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried `onDragEnd` event of HTML but it works for whole input element, not slider of the element.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Does this approach work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199098/html5-is-there-an-onrelease-like-event-for-input-type-range

Comment: Yes. I searched but did not come across this.Thank you.

Comment: I think you may want an `onChange` handler that fires for all the intermediate changes, but then calls a debounced "expensive" callback only when the slider change rate falls below the debounce threshold.

Comment: @OğuzcanBudumlu cool :) in that case you can probably just delete the question, since this has been asked and answered elsewhere

Comment: @DrewReese I have not thought of this approach, but it seems like a good idea. What should I use for this approach?

Comment: For a simple HTML input type range, a change event should only be dispatched when the user releases the mouse button (or equivalent gesture), so it should only update when the target value is reached. Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `onChange` handler on an *uncontrolled* input slider to manage a debounced "expensive" callback, you can utilize `setTimeout` to call the real callback once expired. Upon every change event reset the timeout. Use a ref to store the timer id.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const timerRef = useRef();

const expensiveCallback = value => {
  console.log('expensiveCallback', value);
  setValue(value); // <-- finally update state, or anything else really
};

const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;

  clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
  timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
    expensiveCallback(value); // <-- re-enclose latest value
  }, 250); // <-- tune this value to what feels best for you
};

return (
  ...

    <input
      type="range"
      min={0}
      max={1000}
      defaultValue={value} // <-- use default value for uncontrolled input
      onChange={changeHandler}
    />

  ...
);
```

[image: Edit getting-last-value-of-slider]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `step` attribute to mention how much user can increment the range value. For instance, we can make `1` as start value and `100` as the last value and `step=100` which will only allow the user to increase value from 0 to 100.

```
  <input type="range" id="volume" name="volume"
         min="1" max="100" step="100">
  <label for="volume">Volume</label>
```

Comment: It does not fully meet my requirement. When I decrease the step count, intermediate values will still trigger the rendering.